# add form (non-nested) dynamically in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

pls can someone explain how I can dynamically add another copy of a form in rails?...been working on this for almost 2hrs. I messed around with .clone() and .appendTo in jquery, but it didnt work. Also, most of the materials I found online (like on railscast #196 and stackoverflow) focused heavily on nested forms. My form is nested, but I actually just want to add the parent form again. The photos which are nested use the html multiple attributes so I'm guessing that will handle multiple files upload for each parent form (btw I'm using paperclip).

If I just need to modify the railscast code please let me know.

Thanks.

```
<%= form_for(@user_book, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
<% if @user_book.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user_book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user_book from been saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% @user_book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <p>hello</p>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "enter title...", id: "book_title" %>
<%= f.text_field :category, placeholder: "enter category..." %>
<%=  file_field_tag 'user_book[user_book_photos_attributes][][photo]', :multiple => true         do |p| %>
   <%= p.file_field :photo %> 
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so when the user clicks on save, all the forms are submitted?

Comment: yes basically...I want user to be able to submit several listings at once.

Comment: can u pls explain the model relationship for the objects that are being created? checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765862/how-to-associate-existing-model-with-new-model-in-rails/12766307#comment17252153_12766307 and see if thats what u want.

Comment: @user_books has many user_book_photos...I also have a book's model being created under certain conditions...but that is done in my model...I dont think it matters here